# Kubernetes Hyperledger Fabric Orderer - Failed to Create new connection

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to set up Hyperledger fabric with kubernetes(1 Master & 1 Minion) Wavenet network configuration.

Kubernetes Version : 1.13.3
Ubuntu Version : 18.04 (bionic)

Below is my deployment and service for orderer .

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: orderer
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: orderer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: orderer
    spec:
      hostname: orderer-example-com
      volumes:
      - name: nfs-volume
        nfs: 
         server: 13.71.xx.xx 
         path: /home/         
      containers:
      - args:
        - orderer
        env:
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE
              value: /home/channel/genesis.block
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD
              value: file
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LEDGERTYPE
              value: json
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS
              value: 127.0.0.1
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT
              value: "7050"
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR
              value: "/home/crypto/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/insurance.com/orderers/orderer.insurance.com/msp"
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID
              value: OrdererMSP
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL
              value: info
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE
              value: /home/crypto/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/insurance.com/orderers/orderer.insurance.com/tls/server.crt
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED
              value: "false"
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY
              value: /home/crypto/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/insurance.com/orderers/orderer.insurance.com/tls/server.key
            - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS
              value: '[/home/crypto/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/insurance.com/orderers/orderer.insurance.com/tls/ca.crt]'
        image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
        name: orderer
        ports:
         - name: orderer-port
           containerPort: 7050
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: "/home/"
                name: nfs-volume
            # - mountPath: "/home/channel"
            #   name: orderer-insurance-com-claim0
            # - mountPath: "/home/crypto/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/insurance.com/orderers/orderer.insurance.com"
            #   name: orderer-insurance-com-claim1        
        workingDir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
      restartPolicy: Always    

 -----
 apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: orderer
spec:
  selector:
    app: orderer
  ports:
   - protocol: TCP
     targetPort: 7050
     port: 7050
     nodePort: 31001
     name: orderer-port
  type: NodePort
```

I have exposed the port 7050 of orderer deployment as a service to the port 31001. The Orderer pod seems to run fine and there is no error in the pod or service. Strangely when i try to **connect the orderer service it always timeout**.

I did check the service and it does exposes the port i.e 7050-->310001. Not sure why I get timeout .

> curl "localhost:31001" also timesout .

Can you please let me know If i am missing anything with kubernetes ?

**Update : Orderer Pod description

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide `kubectl describe po orderer`?

Comment: @Crou: updated with snap of orderer pod describition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think

```
- name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS
  value: 127.0.0.1
```

will work as this means the orderer is only listening in the loopback address inside the container.  Try setting the value to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I tested out with  localhost ,0.0.0.0,127.0.0.1 options , no luck did not work !

Comment: How exactly are you trying to access the orderer?  You should be able to access via `nodeIP:nodePort`

Comment: I access with the specified hostname i.e orderer-example-com.

Comment: that is not going to work .... that's not going to be the name used internally by Kube